# Python assert_has_calls fails with order of attributes of object parameter different

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pytest, python-unittest

I have an assertion like this -

```
obj_instance_1 = SomeType(a=1,b=2,c=3)
//invoke the test function
mock_calls = [
            mock.call(param1=obj_instance_1, param2=mocked_obj),
            mock.call(param1=obj_instance_1, param2=mocked_obj),
        ]
mock_instance.assert_has_calls(mock_calls)
```

`assert_has_calls` assertion fails with the error-

```
Expected: [call(param2=<MagicMock name='SomeName' id='140133686336928'>, param1=<SomeType(a=1,b=2,c=3)>),
call(param2=<MagicMock name='SomeName' id='140133686336928'>, param1=<SomeType(a=1,b=2,c=3)>)]
Actual: 
[call(param2=<MagicMock name='SomeName' id='140133686336928'>, param1=<SomeType(b=2,a=1,c=3)>),
call(param2=<MagicMock name='SomeName' id='140133686336928'>, param1=<SomeType(b=2,a=1,c=3)>)]
```

The only difference I see is the order of attributes of param1 object are different in Expected and Actual. But the values of attributes of the object are same. Why would it be causing the test to fail?

Comment: test in a shell or somewhere `SomeType(a=1,b=2,c=3) == SomeType(a=1,b=2,c=3)`. Maybe `SomeType` might need to implement `__eq__`

Comment: @jamylak yes, that returns true.

Comment: And also `SomeType(a=1,b=2,c=3) == SomeType(b=2,a=1,c=3)`?